# Recyclerview with timer reusing the old views

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a list of 20 custom count up timers in Recyclerview, if i start first one, the 14th or 15th row also showing same timer in the textview. I guess the timer is holding the reference to the first textview and it is updating it continuously which is reused in 14th or 15th row. Can any one tell me how to do this efficiently. Thanks in Advance.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private CountAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAdapter = new CountAdapter(getCount(), this);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    private List<String> getCount() {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            strings.add(i + "");
        }
        return strings;
    }

}
```

**CountAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CountAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CountAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "CountAdapter";
    private final List<String> mData;
    private final List<CountUpTimer> mCountUpList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<Boolean> mSelectedRows = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Context mContext;

    public CountAdapter(List<String> mData, Context mContext) {
        this.mData = mData;
        this.mContext = mContext;

        mCountUpList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
            mCountUpList.add(i, null);
        }
        mSelectedRows.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
            mSelectedRows.add(i, false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                         int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v, mContext, mCountUpList, mSelectedRows);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        checkTimerStatus(holder, position);
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + position + " " + String.valueOf(mCountUpList.get(position)));
    }

    private void checkTimerStatus(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        CountUpTimer countUpTimer = mCountUpList.get(position);
        if (countUpTimer != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "checkTimerStatus: " + position);
            countUpTimer.setOnTickListener(new CountUpTimer.OnTickListener() {
                @Override
                public void OnTick(long elapsed) {
                    holder.mTimeText.setText(elapsed + "");
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.mTimeText.setText("00:00:00");
        }

        boolean state = mSelectedRows.get(position);
        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(state);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            CountUpTimer.OnTickListener, View.OnClickListener {
        private static final String TAG = "ViewHolder";
        private final Context mContext;
        private final ArrayList<Boolean> mSelectedRows;
        private final TextView mTimeText;
        private final ImageButton mStartButton;
        private final CheckBox mCheckBox;
        private final List<CountUpTimer> mCountUpList;

        public ViewHolder(View v, Context mContext, List<CountUpTimer> mCountUp,
                          ArrayList<Boolean> mSelectedRows) {

            super(v);
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mCountUpList = mCountUp;
            this.mSelectedRows = mSelectedRows;
            mTimeText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
            mStartButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ibPlay);
            mCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            mStartButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.ibPlay:
                    final CountUpTimer upTimer = new CountUpTimer(100);
                    upTimer.setOnTickListener(this);
                    upTimer.start();
                    mCountUpList.set(getAdapterPosition(), upTimer);
                    break;

                case R.id.checkBox:
                    mSelectedRows.set(getAdapterPosition(),
                            !mSelectedRows.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void OnTick(long elapsed) {

            mTimeText.setText(elapsed + "");
        }
    }

}
```

**CountUpTimer.java**

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class CountUpTimer {

    private final long interval;
    private long base;
    public long mElapsedTime;
    private OnTickListener onTickListener;

    public CountUpTimer(long interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void start() {
        base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(MSG));
    }

    public void stop() {
        handler.removeMessages(MSG);
    }

    public void reset() {
        synchronized (this) {
            base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        }
    }

    public void setOnTickListener(OnTickListener onTickListener) {
        this.onTickListener = onTickListener;
    }

    private static final int MSG = 1;

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            synchronized (CountUpTimer.this) {
                long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - base;
                if (onTickListener != null) {
                    mElapsedTime = elapsedTime;
                    onTickListener.OnTick(elapsedTime);
                }
                sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), interval);
            }
        }
    };

    interface OnTickListener {
        void OnTick(long elapsed);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a solution myself, Hope this helps someone https://github.com/saikiran91/Multiple-Timers-in-Recyclerview

Answer (score -1):

This might happen because you are not updating your holder.mTimeText every time in onBindViewHolder. ie your code is not reaching the statement: ,hence the view is recycling the items.

```
            holder.mTimeText.setText(elapsed + "");
```

every time a view is updated
Try setting

```
if(countUpTimer != null) {
 holder.mTimeText.setText(elapsed + "");
}
```

or just anything for that matter to see if it works